# Proof verification of lcm(a,b,c) = lcm(lcm(a,b),c)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Let $lcm(x,y,z,...)=[x,y,z,...]$. Please help me check my proof for errors. thanks!

Prove that $[a,b,c]=[[a,b],c]$

Proof:

Suppose $m=[a,b,c]$ which implies $a|m$, $b|m$, and $c|m$.
Let $[a,b]=k$ which implies $a|k$ and $b|k$.
Suppose $[[a,b],c]= \phi =[k,c]$ which implies $k| \phi$ and $c|\phi$.
Since $a|k$, $b|k$, and $k|\phi$ then $a|\phi$, $b|\phi$, and $c|\phi$. However, $m=[a,b,c]$ which by definition implies $m \leq \phi$.

Case 1: $m< \phi$, since $a|m$, $b|m$, $c|m$, and $a|\phi$, $b|\phi$, $c|\phi$ then it must be that $[[a,b],c]=m$. Thus, $[a,b,c]=[[a,b],c]$.

Case2: $m= \phi$, $[a,b,c]=[[a,b],c]$.

Therefore, in both cases $[a,b,c]=[[a,b],c]$.

Q.E.D.

Comment: You are lost in case $1$ I think

Comment: As a side note please use minimum number of variables possible. Use of so many variables makes the proof confusing.

Comment: edited case 1. i think it looks more convincing now. thanks

Comment: I still don't know why and how you conclude that if $a|m,b|,c|m$ and $a|\phi,b|\phi,c|\phi$ then $m=\phi$

Comment: since m is less than $\phi$ then it must the lesser common multiple of a,b,c.. would that be an erroneous reasoning?

Comment: i think understand what you mean now. this needs more refinement.

Comment: I suppose yes. If you had that $a|m,b|,c|m$ and $[a,b,m]=\phi$ then you could combine it with $m\le\phi$ to say that $m=\phi$ but at present it seems not so convincing to me.

Comment: Would you like me to construct a proof different from your's?

Comment: [a,b,m] = $\phi$? sure i'm okay with you constructing a proof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases where you need to prove the equality of $[a,b] $ and $(a,b)$ things, you should try to show that left hand side divides riht hand side and vice versa.

Now, let

$[a,b,c]=m $ and $[[a,b],c]=l $, then notice that $a,b,c|m$.

Also,

$[a,b]|l \ \text{and}\  c|l \implies a,b,c|l$. Since, $[a,b,c]=m\implies \color{red}{m|l}$

Then,

$[a,b]|[a,b,c] \ \text{and}\ c|[a,b,c]\implies [[a,b],c]|[a,b,c]\implies \color{blue}{l|m}$

So, $l|m$ and $m|l\implies l=m$

Comment: I'm a little bit not so convinced with how $[a,b]|[a,b,c]$ and $c|[a,b,c]$ implies $[[a,b],c]|[a,b,c]$...

Comment: @TheLastCipher, if $x|p$ and $y|p$ then $[x,y]|p$. Do you agree with it?

Comment: oh right. thanks!